# Pricing on product page only shown with campaign code, but can I omit it from the canonical URL?

Tags: canonical-url, ecommerce, pricing, campaigns

I have a product page in the following format:

`example.com/products/brand?campaignCode=<a campaignCode>`

The `/brand` page shows generic information about the brand (name, description, image, etc.), and then shows a list of available offers. The available offers are determined by the inputted campaign code.

You can also access the page without supplying a `campaignCode`. In that case, the page shows offers from a default campaign code.

Campaign codes may expire, so having potentially expired campaign codes show up in search results seems like a minor annoyance. (Expired campaign codes are handled gracefully by our site, but I want to avoid users searching for a specific brand and then being presented with a link containing a `campaignCode`.

I'm wondering whether I should put a canonical tag on the page, which links to the base `/brand` page without any query parameters.

Can I use canonical tags pointing to my base brand-page to prevent potentially expired `campaignCodes` from showing up in search results?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to avoid users searching for a specific brand and then being presented with a link containing a `campaignCode`

If you want to keep search engines from indexing any campaign code URLs besides the default one, then a canonical tag is the only solution that makes sense. Noindex tags could work, but a canonical tag is much better for SEO.

As you suggested, put canonical tags on all of your campaign code pages and have it point to your brand page. Then only the main brand page should show in search results.